# Integer i = 23; versus Integer i = new Integer(23); Previous answers not satisfactory

Tags: java, wrapper

I understand that an identical question has been asked before-
[what is difference between integer a = 5 and new Integer(5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604768/what-is-difference-between-integer-a-5-and-new-integer5)

However, none of the answers is satisfactory to me-

My question is simply this-
If I say Integer i = 23; it is clearly creating an object i of type Integer. All the Integer methods are available to it. So why is it different from an explicit instantiation- Integer i = new Integer(23) ?

Any insight into this will be much appreciated.

Comment: What didn't you understand about the previous question's answers?

Comment: Read about flyweight pattern.

Comment: The previous answers don't give an answer to the simple question I have above. They give a lot of other facts.. useful, but not the answer to the question

Comment: The first sentence in the accepted answer says quite clearly what is happening.

Comment: @Sotirios, The first sentence just says it uses autoboxing. However, the left hand side of the expression is still an Integer object. So why is it different from new Integer(5)?

Comment: The answers are very clear: `new` creates a new instance and autoboxing can use a cached value. This results in the differences when comparing both objects.

Comment: No, the left hand side is a variable of type `Integer`.

Comment: You should consider looking at the source code of `Integer#valueOf(int)`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Or, even better, read some [Effective Java](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151).

Comment: I think I now understand based on what @kapep has said.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, What do you mean a variable of type Integer? It is a reference variable isn't it? If so, what does it point to? An object..

Comment: The left hand side of an assignment is a _variable_. That is the first distinction you need to make. A variable is different from a reference which is different from an object. The right hand side of an assignment is an expression that resolves to a value. In this case that value is a reference value that is the result of boxing conversion. That boxing conversion involved, somewhere internally, a `new Integer(X)` to be invoked. Just read up on boxing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I looked at Integer.valueOf(int). What it says is that it returns a reference to an Integer instance. The key is (others have pointed this out) that for values in the range of -128 thru' 127, it uses an interned Integer object rather than creating a new object. But it IS an object nevertheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I say `Integer i = 23;` it is clearly creating an object `i` of type `Integer`.

No, it *returns* a reference to an object of type `Integer`. Whether a `new` one is *created* or an existing one (from the JVM's constant pool) is re-used is at the discretion of your JVM.

For `int` literal values from the range –128 to 127 it is even *required* that `Integer` constants are pooled and a new instance never be created.

Comment: ...just as the accepted answer to the linked question says.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Oh, well, yes.

Comment: I really don't see how we could explain it to OP better than that answer, which he has already read. He just needs to re-read and re-think.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Neither do I but I cannot vote for closing a question.

Comment: By the way, if the number is `23`, it **isn't** at the discretion of the VM. It's mandatory to return the same object for the `-128...127` range. Beyond that, it is indeed up to the implementation.

Comment: @5gon12eder,  I think I understand now. (similar to String interning, but only for numbers inside the range -128 thru' 127).. Thanks.

Comment: Almost exactly like string interning, actually.

Comment: @biziclop Thanks, updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @biziclop But *only for literals*: `If the value p being boxed is an integer literal of type int between -128 and 127 inclusive [...]`