# Difference between Integer.parseint vs new Integer

Tags: java

What is the difference between `Integer.parseInt("5")` and `new Integer("5")`. I saw that in code both types are used, what is the difference between them?

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18604959/956660$

Comment: Search the documentation and you have an answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is difference between integer a = 5 and new Integer(5)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604768/what-is-difference-between-integer-a-5-and-new-integer5)

Comment: @JavaKid Because it could have been answered by just looking in the API documentation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

They use the same implementation :

```
public Integer(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
this.value = parseInt(s, 10);
}

public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
return parseInt(s,10);
}
```

The main difference is that `parseInt` returns a primitive (`int`) while the `Integer` constructor returns (not surprisingly) an `Integer` instance.

If you need an `int`, use `parseInt`. If you need an Integer instance, either call `parseInt` and assign it to an Integer variable (which will auto-box it) or call `Integer.valueOf(String)`, which is better than calling the `Integer(String)` constructor, since the `Integer` constructor doesn't take advantage of the `IntegerCache` (since you always get a new instance when you write `new Integer(..)`).

I don't see a reason to ever use `new Integer("5")`. `Integer.valueOf("5")` is better if you need an `Integer` instance, since it will return a cached instance for small integers.

Answer (score 4):

[The Java documentation for Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer(java.lang.String)) states :

> The string is converted to an int value in exactly the manner used by the parseInt method for radix 10.

So I guess its the same.

Comment: Using the constructor you create a new instance of Integer, which is not the case for `Integer.parseInt()`